# Aggregation with Mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hey im trying some aggregation on mongodb using moongose:
I got this data:

```
[
  {
    "school": "1",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "person": "X",
        "color": "A"
      },
      {
        "person": "X",
        "color": "B"
      },
      {
        "person": "Y",
        "color": "A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "school": "2",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "person": "Z",
        "color": "A"
      },
      {
        "person": "Y",
        "color": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I think the data explaisn it self, What i want to get as result is,
when i query for the school that matches '1'. i would like to get this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "X",
    "colors": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Y",
    "colors": ["A"]
  }
]
```

I used aggregation before, but i cant figure to get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this aggregation query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "school": "1"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$preferences"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$preferences.person",
    "colors": {
      "$addToSet": "$preferences.color" // $addToSet used here only to add distinct color 
    }
  }
})
```

Edit If you want count the number of `color` then used group with `sum` as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "school": "1"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$preferences"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$preferences.color",
    "appears": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
})
```

**EDIT**

As per your new requirement you should do following aggregation:

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$preferences"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "person": "$preferences.person",
            "color": "$preferences.color"
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.person",
        "colors": {
            "$push": {
                "color": "$_id.color",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "person": "$_id",
        "colors": 1
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Hey man thankyou i cannot believe that i was trying this in the hard way and was so simple, i was using match the id, project person: $preferences.person, color: $preferences.color, unwind the person, group _id: person, colors:$addToSet: $color and didnt make it work always was getting the the person but each color repeating into each person.

Comment: What about if i would like to get  again with the school matches "1"
```
[
  {
    "_id": "A", // Color
    "appears": 2 // in 2 persons
  },
  {
    "_id": "B",
    "appears": 1
  }
]
```
@yogesh

Comment: As per your query you first project them as `{"$project":{"person":"$preferences.person","color":"$preferences.color"}}` so this return array of `person and color` as like this `"person" : [ "X", "X", "Y" ], "color" : [ "A", "B", "A" ]` and after that you used `unwind to person`  `{"$unwind":"$person"}` it only unwind `person` array not a `color` array looks like this `"person" : "X", "color" : [ "A", "B", "A" ]` after group by `person` and then you used `addToSet as color ` so color contains array of array like this `"_id" : "Y", "color" : [ [ "A", "B", "A" ] ]` .

Comment: Hello @yogesh, i would like to know if you can help me on this one, my data set changed to this:
`
[
  {
    "school": "1",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "person": "X",
        "color": "A"
      },
      {
        "person": "X",
        "color": "B"
      },
      {
        "person": "Y",
        "color": "A"
      },
      {
        "person": "X",
        "color": "A"
      },
      {
        "person": "Y",
        "color": "A"
      }
    ]
  }
]
`

Comment: What happend now is that the combination of the person and color can be duplicated, so i would like to get something like this :

** [
  {
    "_id": "X",
    "colors": [
      {
        "color": "A" ,
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "color": "B",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Y",
    "colors": [
      {
        "color": "A" ,
        "count": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
**

Comment: @ErickArroyo what exactly you want to find out ?

Comment: as you can see, now the object { "person": "X", "color": "A" } appears twice in the preferences array, i would like to return the counter of how many times is appearing that color for a X person

Comment: Thank you, but im getting this:
**
[
  {
    "person": "X",
    "color": "A",
    "colorCount": 2
  },
  {
    "person": "X",
    "color": "B",
    "colorCount": 1
  },
  {
    "person": "Y",
    "color": "A",
    "colorCount": 2
  }
]
**
Is there any way that i can group by person like this data set:
**
[
  {
    "person": "X",
    "colors": [
      {
        "color": "A" ,
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "color": "B",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "person",
    "colors": [
      {
        "color": "A" ,
        "count": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
**

Comment: i updated my answer, i would like to know if i can format the response that way

Comment: Hey @yogesh i didnt have time to test it before, i just did and ir work as i expected, thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't allow me, says I need 15 of reputation, I will as soon as I can